# Generating automatic dayly, weekly and monthly reports in Django

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks

I would like to generate periodical reports and have them sent to the users.

The user should be able to select frequency and date/time of sending (e.g. every day at 9.00, every week on monday, etc.), in addiction to other info relevant to the report content itself.

What do you think would be a good solution to integrate this in Django?

Comment: What are you asking for, a report generator?  Or something that fires off the report generator?

Comment: I'm looking for the right approach to have some scheduled task working on the Django database and fire off reports. Possibly managing it from Django and not externally by cron scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing it using cron (the unix job scheduler) in case you are on a unix system.

You can use [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/), a Django module that wraps the cron job scheduling
But I usually write the task to be scheduled as a [django custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), and schedule a regular cron job calling this.

If you have django installed in a virtual python environment, you should run a script activating the vitualenv and then calling the command (see example below).

---

On a unix system, using virtualenv:

script example (script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
python /path/to/django/project/manage.py custom_command
```

add line in cron (command: `crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh >> /path/to/log/file.log 2>&1
```

replace the *s with the desired time and frequency (details in the default crontab file)

To install the new scheduled task, simply save the crontab file

Comment: The guess the cron approach can definitely work but I'm looking for something a little bit more integrated. Will have a look at django-cron. Any clue about Celery, would it be an option?

Comment: Yes you can do that with celery. I never used celery for that (mostly for queuing long tasks), but  there is a Periodic Task model in celery: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html